# #LinkedIn API call on a showcase page

Tags: linkedin-api

I am trying to make API call on a showcase LinkedIn page. However, when I register the APP in the Developer portal, it does not recognize the showcase LinkedIn page. Is there a way I can register an APP on a showcase LinkedIn Page?
[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Scimv.png)